# Getting data from URL (like php's $_GET) for jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I'm wanting to do is take a URL like myurl.com/page.php?data1=x&data2=y&data3=z and get each piece of data and use it in a jQuery function. Is there any built in way to do that?

To clarify, when I navigate to (say, pasting the url into the address bar, or going to it via a bookmark) I want jQuery to do something with that data.

As a bonus, if it also includes something to check if the data is set to something, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do it would be if your javascript code is embedded in a php file (not an external link to a .js file), you could just do a PHP print right in between your `<script></script>` tags. It would work with bookmarks and pasting the URL to the address bar.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var get_var;
get_var = <? print $_GET['varname']; ?>;
// some jQuery code here
</script>
```

**This should only be used as a proof of concept.** This is vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), and should not be used in production. This [list of XSS prevention techniques](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) is a good place to start (but outside the scope of the OP's question).

Comment: I think that might actually work exactly like I need. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: Though, be smart - this is not very practical as it is extremely vulnerable to code injection.

Comment: At current, this is mostly a proof of concept. But for code going live, I agree, and would come up with something a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for how to get values from the *query string*. Here's pretty much the same question:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a plugin like [jQuery.url.js](http://ajaxcssblog.com/jquery/url-read-request-variables/) would work or maybe [Url parser](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/urlParser).