# Javascript / jquery - like PHPs $_GET

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable set in my url:

```
http://mydomain.com?myvar=1
```

Now I need to check this when the page loads. I would normally do this in PHP but I need to use some jQuery. What I want to do is something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var somevar = $GET['myvar'];
    if (somevar = '1') {
        $('#someDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

How can I do this if its at all posible?

Comment: To do it client side in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values  To do it in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083900/getting-data-from-url-like-phps-get-for-jquery-ajax?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will do that:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```